# Degree 0 rational function on unit sphere.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, polynomials

Suppose I have a degree zero homogenous rational function which has constant value on unit sphere. Does it mean it has constant value over $\mathbb R^n- 0$? If yes, why? By a degree zero  homogenous rational function I mean a rational function of the  form $P/Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are homogenous function of the same degree.

Comment: And this function of yours is defined on...?

Comment: What's a degree zero rational function?

Comment: By degree $0$, I mean rational functions $P/Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ have same degree. Say it is defined for all values except 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. If $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}$, then 
$$
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{P(\lambda v)}{Q(\lambda v)},
$$
where $\lambda = \| x \|$ and $v = x/ \|x\|$. Since $P$ and $Q$ are both homogeneous, say of degree $d$, 
$$
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{P(\lambda v)}{Q(\lambda v)} =\frac{\lambda^d}{\lambda^d} \frac{P(v)}{Q(v)} = c,
$$
where $c$ is the constant that it achieves on the unit sphere (since $v$ is of unit norm, $P(v)/Q(v) = c$).

Therefore, $P/Q$ is constant on all of $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$.

Comment: Just  a couple of spelling errors. BTW can a non-constant rational  $f :R-S \to R$  (with finite $S$)  be constant on the unit sphere when $n>1$?